# How to join three tables with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join three tables to pull back a list of distinct blog posts with associated assets (images etc) but I keep coming up a cropper. The three tablets are `tblBlog`, `tblAssetLink` and `tblAssets`. The Blog tablet hold the blog, the asset table holds the assets and the Assetlink table links the two together.

`tblBlog.BID` is the PK in blog, `tblAssets.AID` is the PK in Assets.

This query works but pulls back multiple posts for the same record. I've tried to use select distinct and group by and even union but as my knowledge is pretty poor with SQL - they all error.

I'd like to also discount any assets that are marked as deleted (tblAssets.Deleted = true) but not hide the associated Blog post (if that's not marked as deleted). If anyone can help - it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Here's my query so far....

```
SELECT dbo.tblBlog.BID,
       dbo.tblBlog.DateAdded,
       dbo.tblBlog.PMonthName,
       dbo.tblBlog.PDay,
       dbo.tblBlog.Header,
       dbo.tblBlog.AddedBy,
       dbo.tblBlog.PContent,
       dbo.tblBlog.Category,
       dbo.tblBlog.Deleted,
       dbo.tblBlog.Intro,
       dbo.tblBlog.Tags,
       dbo.tblAssets.Name,
       dbo.tblAssets.Description,
       dbo.tblAssets.Location,
       dbo.tblAssets.Deleted AS Expr1,
       dbo.tblAssetLink.Priority
FROM   dbo.tblBlog
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAssetLink
         ON dbo.tblBlog.BID = dbo.tblAssetLink.BID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAssets
         ON dbo.tblAssetLink.AID = dbo.tblAssets.AID
WHERE  ( dbo.tblBlog.Deleted = 'False' )

ORDER  BY dbo.tblAssetLink.Priority, tblBlog.DateAdded DESC
```

*EDIT*

Changed the `Where` and the `order by`....

Expected output:

```
tblBlog.BID = 123

tblBlog.DateAdded = 12/04/2015

tblBlog.Header = This is a header

tblBlog.AddedBy = Persons name

tblBlog.PContent = *text*

tblBlog.Category = Category name

tblBlog.Deleted = False

tblBlog.Intro = *text*

tblBlog.Tags = Tag, Tag, Tag

tblAssets.Name = some.jpg

tblAssets.Description = Asset desc

tblAssets.Location = Location name

tblAssets.Priority = True
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: sorry, i just spotted that and updated above

Comment: I guess the query returns a row for every asset. Do you expect a different outcome? How do you expect multiple assets to be returnt?

Comment: That is correct but what i would like to get is just one asset per blog post (top one ordered by Priority).

Comment: `tblAssetLink.Priority` and `dbo.tblBlog.Deleted`are really varchar instead of bit?

Comment: No, they're bit. I was going by the output from sql query browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @b TABLE ( BID INT )
DECLARE @a TABLE ( AID INT )
DECLARE @ba TABLE
    (
      BID INT ,
      AID INT ,
      Priority INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @b
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 )

INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 4 )

INSERT  INTO @ba
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 2 )


SELECT  *
FROM    @b b
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                a.*
                      FROM      @ba ba
                                JOIN @a a ON a.AID = ba.AID
                      WHERE     ba.BID = b.BID
                      ORDER BY  Priority
                    ) o
```

Output:

```
BID AID
1   1
2   1
```

Something like:

```
SELECT  b.BID ,
        b.DateAdded ,
        b.PMonthName ,
        b.PDay ,
        b.Header ,
        b.AddedBy ,
        b.PContent ,
        b.Category ,
        b.Deleted ,
        b.Intro ,
        b.Tags ,
        o.Name ,
        o.Description ,
        o.Location ,
        o.Deleted AS Expr1 ,
        o.Priority
FROM    dbo.tblBlog b
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    TOP 1 
                                a.* ,
                                al.Priority
                      FROM      dbo.tblAssetLink al
                                JOIN dbo.tblAssets a ON al.AID = a.AID
                      WHERE     b.BID = al.BID
                      ORDER BY al.Priority
                    ) o
WHERE   b.Deleted = 'False'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join three tables unless they all have the same attribute. It would work if all tables had BID, but the second join is trying to join AID. Which wont work. They all have to have BID.

Comment: AID and BID are both held within AssetLink - thats the table that joins them both together

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments

> i would like to get is just one asset per blog post (top one ordered
>   by Priority)

You can change your query as following. I suggest changing the join with `dbo.tblAssetLink` to filtered one, which contains only one (highest priority) link for every blog.

```
SELECT dbo.tblBlog.BID,
       dbo.tblBlog.DateAdded,
       dbo.tblBlog.PMonthName,
       dbo.tblBlog.PDay,
       dbo.tblBlog.Header,
       dbo.tblBlog.AddedBy,
       dbo.tblBlog.PContent,
       dbo.tblBlog.Category,
       dbo.tblBlog.Deleted,
       dbo.tblBlog.Intro,
       dbo.tblBlog.Tags,
       dbo.tblAssets.Name,
       dbo.tblAssets.Description,
       dbo.tblAssets.Location,
       dbo.tblAssets.Deleted AS Expr1,
       dbo.tblAssetLink.Priority
FROM   dbo.tblBlog
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (SELECT BID, AID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BID ORDER BY [Priority] DESC) as N 
        FROM dbo.tblAssetLink) AS filteredAssetLink
         ON dbo.tblBlog.BID = filteredAssetLink.BID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAssets
         ON filteredAssetLink.AID = dbo.tblAssets.AID
WHERE dbo.tblBlog.Deleted = 'False' AND filteredAssetLink.N = 1
ORDER  BY tblBlog.DateAdded DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this would work fine but i got to @Giorgi Nakeuri post first so i've used his solution.